# How concurrency work with coredata?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm reading this link for concurrency in core-data

[Coredata - Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html)

**My app flow is:**

One thread is contentiously inserting information in the background. And the user is playing in an app and update something.

-> Due to background thread all updates will be saved in database automatically as it will save my main context. So one can not discard what the changes he made as it will save automatically.

Before I go to update my core logic of inserting information, I need your advice.

- Is there any way to handle my scenario easily?
- Will concurrency work with the background and main thread?

Also, let me know if any demo or tutorial you have/finds. So I may refer it.

Thanks

Comment: It may help you: https://cocoacasts.com/more-core-data-and-concurrency/

Comment: @SivajeeBattina "Remember that this means that the changes of the private managed object context are pushed to its parent managed object context when a save operation is performed."--> Does this mean that we can discard or save private context will work independently?

Comment: Or if we have private context running and save main context will ignore private context updates?